# How to change TextField's highlighted text color on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-textinputlayout, android-compose-textfield

In currently transitioning my app to Jetpack compose and I'm facing some problems to adapt my current color palette in some cases.

I have some `TextInputLayout` on my xml files that inherit the highlight text color from SECUNDARY color on my theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/red</item>
    ...
</style>
```

[image: TextInputLayout with theme's secondary colour - xml]

The problem is that my `TextField` on compose inherit the highlight text color from the PRIMARY color on `MaterialTheme`.

```
MaterialTheme(
    colors = Colors(
        primary = Color.Blue,
        ...
        secondary = Color.Red,
        ...
    ),
    content = content,
    typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
    shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes,
) {
   TextField(...)
}
```

[image: TextField with theme's primary color - compose]

I overrode the `colors` parameter on `TextField` but none seems to affect this colour.

Would there be a way of overriding the highlight color on compose without changing the `colors` on `MaterialTheme`? I would like to avoid that since it could cause problems on other screens that would use same theme.

Comment: Commenting only so googling is easier: textSelectHandle for compose, text selection color

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The colors used for text selection by text and text field components are provided by [**`LocalTextSelectionColors.current`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/selection/package-summary#LocalTextSelectionColors()).

You can provide a custom [**`TextSelectionColors`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/selection/TextSelectionColors) using:

```
val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
    handleColor = Red,
    backgroundColor = Red.copy(alpha = 0.4f)
)

CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors) {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(cursorColor = Red)
    )
}
```

If you want to change also the cursor color add `colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(cursorColor = Red)`.

[image]

Comment: What about for a BasicTextField?

Comment: @CharlesWoodson use the same LocalTextSelectionColors

Comment: It will work for BasicTextField also

Comment: Can I define it at the Theme level? Wrapping it in TextField makes it become writing more duplication code.