# Change color of selection text in SelectionContainer in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change the color of the **SelectionContainer** but I don't see any option in the parameter section to make a change here. I've also took a look at the internal code and I couldn't see anything related with *colors*. Docs doesn't mention nothing about this.

Question: Is there any way to change the selection color or isn't that possible?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779305/how-to-change-textfields-highlighted-text-color-on-jetpack-compose/68780835#68780835

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [TextSelectionColors](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/selection/TextSelectionColors) to set the color of the selection.

To do this you need to wrap your `Text` in a `CompositionLocalProvider`. The colors used for text selection by text and text field components are provided by [LocalTextSelectionColors.current](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/selection/package-summary#LocalTextSelectionColors()).

You can provide a custom `TextSelectionColors` using:

```kotlin
val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
    handleColor = Red,
    backgroundColor = Red.copy(alpha = 0.4f)
)

CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors) {
    SelectionContainer {
        Text(
            text = coin.description,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
        )
    }
}
```

P.S. Part of the question was copied from this SO answer - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780835/5698740)