# What is the difference between the different options under PointerIconDefaults in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
Column(
   Modifier.padding(top = 300.dp).pointerHoverIcon(PointerIconDefaults.Text)) {
       SelectionContainer {
           Column {
               Text("Selectable text")
               Text(
                     modifier = Modifier.pointerHoverIcon(PointerIconDefaults.Hand, true),
                     text = "Selectable text with hand"
               )
           }
        }
    Text("Just text with global pointerIcon")
}
```

`PointerIconDefaults.Text`:

[image]

`PointerIconDefaults.Hand`:

[image]

I don't see any difference between `PointerIconDefaults.Hand` and `PointerIconDefaults.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you expect from using this modifier since your image shows a floating toolbar. If you need to change how floating toolbar looks like, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68966424/3585796). If you need to change the selection color, check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69525220/3585796).

`Modifier.pointerHoverIcon` change the appearance of the mouse pointer over the item. To see this, for example you can connect a BLE mouse to your Android device, not sure if this can be checked in the Emulator.

[image]

Any `Text` has `PointerIconDefaults.Text` by default.